# How to upgrade mysql5.0 to 5.5 on CentOS

Tags: centos, mysql5.5

I am trying to upgrade mysql from 5.0 to 5.5 on my local server. I have CentOS 5.8.

I have php5.3 installed. When I type

```
yum remove mysql mysql-*
```

The following comes out.

```
Removing:
 mysql                x86_64       5.0.95-1.el5_7.1       installed       8.2 M
 mysql-server         x86_64       5.0.95-1.el5_7.1       installed        22 M
Removing for dependencies:
 perl-DBD-MySQL       x86_64       3.0007-2.el5           installed       328 k
 php53-mysql          x86_64       5.3.3-7.el5_8          installed       210 k
```

Q1. Should I type yes to remove all? If it is no, how to avoid removing php53-mysql? Do I need it?

Q2. After removing it, I am going to type the following. Is it correct.

```
yum install mysql55 mysql55-server --enablerepo=webtatic
service mysqld start
mysql_upgrade
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw: why are you trying to upgrade to mysql5.5? Is there some new functionality that you need?

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest you use mysql 5.5 from IUS instead of webtatic.  With it, you can also get [yum-plugin-replace](http://wiki.iuscommunity.org/Doc/ClientUsageGuide#Upgrading_Stock_RHEL_Packages_to_IUS_Packages), which will let you do `yum replace mysql --replace-with=mysql55` and it will figure out the dependencies and install the new package.  This would avoid removing php53-mysql (which you need if you have any PHP code that interacts with MySQL).

Comment: And that's my "clever thing for today on SF", and it's not even 7am.  Thank you!

Comment: My goodness, that `yum-plugin-replace` might prove to be a godsend for me.

Answer (score 1):

Webtatic has added yum-plugin-replace to it's repository, and the guide is updated to allow upgrading via this method:

http://www.webtatic.com/packages/mysql55/

Assuming CentOS 5.x:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el5/latest.rpm
yum install mysql.`uname -i` yum-plugin-replace
yum replace mysql --replace-with mysql55
```

Comment: this worked for me but I had to run `rpm -e mysql.i386 --nodeps` first

Answer (score 0):

A1 > Instead of doing yum remove. Do rpm -e on the package name, that would help retaining the dependencies

```
 rpm -e mysql-server.
```

A2> Your second set of instructions look good. Since this is more of a fresh install, I think you MAY need to run the following steps instead of mysql_upgrade.

```
 Firstly, run mysql_install_db
 Secondly, run mysql_secure_installation
```

Comment: `rpm -e package` will produce an error if there are installed packages that have the package as a dependency.

Comment: rpm {-e|--erase} [--nodeps] PACKAGE_NAME